# how to convert firebase timestamp to only date and time in html?

Tags: html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

so I want to know that how can I convert firebase "timestamp" to only date and time... when I am using the `toDate()` method its showing me full output
OUTPUT:
 `Wed Jun 09 2021 23:32:02 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

and I want my output to be like this:
EXPECTED OUTPUT:
`Wed Jun 09 2021 23:32:02`

that's it !

how to convert it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore sdk `toDate()` returns a javascript Date object. So you can format  it the way you need from there. There are no other formatting options from the Firestore sdk.

There is more information on the Firestore Timestamp here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp

For formatting, one option (of many in JavaScript) is [dateformat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dateformat). It is much smaller than something like `moment.js` or `dayjs` and sufficient if all you are doing is formatting date/time output for display.

To format string for your desired output would be:
`ddd mmm dd yyyy HH:MM:SS`